# How to set session for login and logout in php?

Tags: php, html, session

I have created session and destroying session in logout.php but if i entered in url(http://localhost/demo/home.php)it showing loggedin.It should be redirect on index.php or display page not found.

What i am achieving- I have login section and there is no issue in that.I am able to login with my credentials and page is redirecting on home.php successfully.From home.php i have logout link and i clicked on that page is redirecting on index.php but if i entered  home.php showing loggedin..
Please help me in this.

**index.php**

```
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

$sel_user = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Username='$username' and Password='$password'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_user);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

if($check_user>0){

echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";
$_SESSION['user_email']=$username;

}

else {

$msg="Username and Password is incorrect.";


}
```

**Home.php**

```
<h2>Home page</h2>
<a href="logout.php">logout</a>
```

**logout.php**

```
       <?php
         session_start();
        if(session_destroy())
                {
                header("Location: index.php");
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: I don't have my computer in front of me right now to show you basic examples of syntax. But just looking at your logout.php, I'm not seeing where you are ending the session. I'm just seeing an if statement. To top it off, I see you actually start session right before that if statement. I have two pages on my projects, one a login and one a logout. - I'm only saying this because I'm not understanding your logout.php. I'll be at my computer in a little if you haven't been helped by then.

Comment: Thanks for help Mr.MattOlivos i solution from ZHorvat Thats working for me

Comment: lol, don't thank me. I didn't do anything, honestly. Have a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `home.php` should check if user is logged in or not. Just add `if` statement at the top.

Something like:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_email']) == FALSE){
     header("Location: index.php");
}
```

also your `logout.php` just creates session and then checks if it's destroyed. For that you could just:

```
unset($_SESSION['user_email']);
```

and your `home.php` would just redirect, since this var is not declared anymore.

Comment: Cool!!!..So i missed if condition in home page..Thanks for helping me.It's working for me perfectly.

Comment: You also missing the exit; after your header method. Voted up however

Comment: Yup..One more information i need..In case there are more than 5 pages.Should i write if condition in all the pages?

Comment: Yes, because page will be shown otherwise. You could use <?php include 'verification.php';?> before html tags and store if statement there.

Answer (score 1):

In your home page

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_email'])){ 
  header("Location: index.php");
}
```

In your logout page

```
<?php 
unset($_SESSION['user_email']);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Also use `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $variable)` in your mysql request to avoid injection sql

```
$sel_user = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username)."' and Password='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password)."'";
```

And check the data received by your POST method before adding to the database.

Comment: In case there are more than 5 pages.Should i write if condition in all the pages?

Comment: Yes you need the script in each page you want to restrict the access.

Comment: Use my example for the mysqli_real_escape_string() i just edit my message